# how to update sql data

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have prices data in db like this:

```
id   date                symbol          open   close
1   2022-06-13 10:00:00 TADAWUL:TASI    12278   12286
2   2022-06-14 10:00:00 TADAWUL:TASI    12038   12114
3   2022-06-15 10:00:00 TADAWUL:TASI    12036   12131
4   2022-06-02 10:00:00 TADAWUL:8070    18      18  
5   2022-06-05 10:00:00 TADAWUL:8070    18      18  
6   2022-06-06 10:00:00 TADAWUL:8070    18      18  
7   2022-06-07 10:00:00 TADAWUL:8070    18      18
```

I want to add 3 more rows under id 3 and id 7. I am using sqlite3 in python.

Comment: Rows in an SQL database are not ordered, so you can't insert them at a particular spot.  Ordering comes from the `ORDER BY` clause.  Are you using the `sqlite3` module, or are you only using pandas?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 and pandas for the dataframe

Comment: If it is very important for you to have the records stored in order, you can add at end, and use a query to copy the data and structure into a temporary table. Then delete original table, `vacuum` it and transfer data back. You then obviously need to define a sort order.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: What @MyICQ described is a horrible practice and is not guaranteed to work.  If you don't provide `ORDER BY`, an SQL database is allowed to return records in any order at all.  Doing a single query twice in a row might return different orderings.  That doesn't usually happen, but the spec allows it.  If you want ordering by symbol and date, then that's what you should specify.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting is done like this:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cur = db.cursor()

row = ('2022-06-22 10:00:00', 'TADAWUL:TASI', 13000, 13999)
cur.execute( "INSERT INTO mytable (date,symbol,open,close) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", row )

row = ('2022-06-22 10:00:00', 'TADAWUL:8070', 19, 19)
cur.execute( "INSERT INTO mytable (date,symbol,open,close) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", row )

db.commit()
```

Comment: I want to insert  under specific rows